# how to set up android mqtt push server

Tags: php, android, service, mqtt

I install xampp-v9   on Windows7 platform   ,android open sql  apache ,and   install  mqtt broker ,sure mqtt service  is  opened,use    mqtt php  manager server  ,when  i  run ,just show   as  follos

Tokudu Android Push Demo
Server status: connect(SAM_MQTT, array(SAM_HOST => '127.0.0.1', SAM_PORT => 1883)); if ($result) { $conn->disconnect(); print_r("Online"); } else { print_r("Offline"); } ?>

so   why?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are asking. Are those commands in the first sentence? If so, pleas format them as code.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly where is that status shown? what code have you deployed? have you verified that you can publish/subscribe to mosquitto or rsmb using any other tools e.g. mosquitto_pub?

Have you looked at the MQTT.org wiki about using MQTT with Android? http://mqtt.org/wiki/mqtt_on_the_android_platform

Answer (score 0):

Tokudu Android Push Demo 
Server status: connect(SAM_MQTT, array(SAM_HOST => '127.0.0.1', SAM_PORT =>1813)); if ($result) { $conn->disconnect(); print_r("Online"); } else { print_r("Offline"); } ?>

above  is  the   issue ,I wan't  to  use  MQTT  to  push  android  message